# phpstorm class doc comment date stackoverflow

Tags: php, environment-variables, phpstorm, code-templates

I want to add a "PHP Class Doc Comment" to my php file. Everything works fine except that ${DATE} doesn't get replaced. I am clearly missing something so obvious! Can I not access this environment variable because it isn't available for this "built-in" template?

The following template

```
/**
 * Project-Name
 * Class ${NAME}
 * User: Brad Goss
 * Date: ${DATE}
 */
```

Results in:

```
/**
 * Project-Name
 * Class PBPermission
 * User: Brad Goss
 * Date: ${DATE}
 */
```

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17507 ? All available "variables" in specific standard file/code templates should be listed in description area.

Comment: Right, ok. So I can't access DATE... Which is kinda silly. My class comments have always been lacking/non-existent. This would have polished it off nicely. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could simply create a **Live Template** and use it instead -- almost all text is static anyway PLUS live template allows you to format date in the format you want (while `$(DATE}` is using system date format only).

Comment: Eek. I definitely don't want to manually type the date, and my name, and the class name. :( No automatic class header comments for me I guess...

Comment: Yes .. you are changing your name every second minute -- how could I forgot about it?.. And date -- where did I said anything about "typing" it? I've only mentioned formatting... Anyway -- the choice is yours -- I've only offered an alternative.

Comment: Absolutely appreciate it too. This is the only viable solution right now for me, so thanks for the suggestion mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to SETTINGS -> IDE SETTINGS -> FILE AND CODE TEMPLATES -> PHP FILE HEADER 
and add the following:

```
@Date    ${DATE}
```

Now when you create a new file the file header comment block will contain the date.

Comment: Only problem is I tend to create all my files using finder. I have finder full screen on my second monitor and it's so much faster browsing files (shortcut links in sidebar for popular folders). So I tend to resort to finder to create files. In PHPStorm I tend to open all my files using CMD-OPTION-O and ignore the project explorer. So unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue...

Comment: Still no fix 1 year later ?